# get QModelIndex from QPersistentModelIndex

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, I need to select row for delete, so I am using a `QPersistentModelIndex`. `QPersistentModelIndex` is working well with multiple row selection, while other methods are not deleting all rows. My problem is, I can't mapToSource with the `QPersistentModelIndex` it needs `QModelIndex`. How can I overcome this?

```
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    filter = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.filter.setSourceModel(model)
    # Set the model/check function
    table_view = QTableView()        
    table_view.setModel(filter)

    # Delete Row using 
    index_list = []                                                          
    for model_index in table_view.selectionModel().selectedRows():       
        index = QPersistentModelIndex(model_index)         
        index_list.append(index)                                         

    if index_list:
       for index in index_list: 
           "The error is here, it only accepts `QModelIndex` and refuses `QPersistentModelIndex`"
           ix      = table_view.model().mapToSource(index.row())  
           # ix      = table_view.model().mapToSource(index)            
           item    = model.itemFromIndex(ix)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert QPersistentModelIndex to QModelIndex you just have to use:

```
for p_index in index_list: 
    index = QModelIndex(p_index)
    ix = table_view.model().mapToSource(index)
```